# I am experimenting "guard" in a playground but I am getting unexpected results

Tags: swift

I have the code (`returning` is a function)

The function clearly returns nil, but the else block is not triggered.

```
var returns: String?
func returning() -> String {
    return nil
}

func nilTest() {
    guard returning != nil else {
        return
    }
    print(returning)
    print("Success")
}
```

Output:

> (Function)
>
> success

Comment: `returning` is a function and you use it as a variable.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text. Copy and paste your code into your question as text. Copy and paste the text of the console into your question as text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to post.

Comment: Based on your error, your guard statement should be: `guard returning() != nil else { return }`. Please post your exact code for more helpful answers.

Comment: for @JohnZ answer I can add that before return you can add some `print("here")` statement to be sure that `guard` works like you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var returns: String?

func returning() -> String? {
    return nil
}

func nilTest() {
    /// Here you use function `returning` as a variable.
    /// Not its value
    guard returning != nil else {
        return
    }
    print(returning)
    print("Success")
}
```

The problem is that `returning` in your code is just a function. Not a result of the function. It has a function type `() -> String?`. Not a `String?`.

To resolve this issue use:

```
guard returning() != nil else {
    return
}
```

instead.

Or, that is more obvious:

```
let myString = returning()
guard myString != nil else {
    return
}
```